# How to make element scrollable while fill the rest of container height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a simple search panel including: Textbox, Result, Pager inside a container.

[image]

Requirement is that the container is flexible, not fixed size. When the container's size changes, its children also change as following:

1. Textbox: width changes, height fixs, anchors at top
2. Result: width changes, height changes, scrollable (show scroll bar if contents overflows)
3. Pager: width changes, height changes, anchors at bottom.

I've managed to archived something by using `TABLE` as container but the result is inconsistent across browser (IE, Firefox, Chrome).

1. IE11

   - w/o content: OK
   - w content: NG: Result expands(breaks layout)
2. Chrome:

   - w/o content: OK
   - w content: OK
   - both: there's still gaps between TR despite of `border-collapse:collapse`
3. Firefox:

   - w/o content: NG: Result shrinks(breaks layout)
   - w content: NG: Result expands(breaks layout)

I'm trying to fix above problems or find another approach for my design. And I need pure css solution because of reasons. Thanks!

```js
$(function() {
  var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    pageSize: 2
  });


  $("#pager").kendoPager({
    dataSource: ds
  });

  $("#container").resizable({
      minHeight: 250,
      minWidth: 250
  });
  
  $("p").hide();
  $("#add").on("click", function() {
    $("p").toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#container table {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#container td {
  padding: 0;
}
#container td>* {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container tr.fit-content {
  height: 1px;
}
#container .scroll-content {
  padding: 2px 0 0;
}
#container .result {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-beta.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-beta.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/js/kendo.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span id="add" class="k-button" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0">
  Toggle Result's contents
</span>
<div id="container">
  <table>
    <tr class="fit-content">
      <td>
        <span class="k-textbox k-space-right">
                    <input type="text"/>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="k-icon k-i-search"></a>
                </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="scroll-content">
        <div class="k-widget result">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse a ligula justo, et varius mauris. Vivamus eleifend feugiat tortor ut egestas. Donec risus diam, vestibulum ut pharetra vitae, scelerisque quis tellus. Fusce pharetra, diam ut facilisis scelerisque, magna nisl viverra lectus, vel malesuada erat odio nec quam. Sed placerat tellus et turpis rhoncus semper. Sed at molestie turpis. Duis purus dui, ornare ut tristique nec, aliquet et purus. Mauris ullamcorper accumsan elit, vel semper justo accumsan non. Aliquam viverra metus nibh. Maecenas tempus, sapien eu semper pellentesque, lacus nisi venenatis purus, id pretium justo ipsum ac lorem.</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fit-content">
      <td>
        <div id="pager">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your container to an exact pixel height, then telling your ".result" to fill 100% of that height. This is why it spills over the other elements. Try setting exact height for the ".result" instead of 100%. Remember to check your padding and margins and how they affect your height and account for this in the number you select.

Also, browsers interpret 100% height differently. Since you are not setting the height of your parent TD and TR, you may cause a collapse with the percentage setting.

Comment: That's the problem, `.result` 's height can't be assigned anything other than 100%. It must be scaled with the container. Maybe a pure css solution isn't possible...

Comment: If you make it 100%, you are squeezing out the other elements. my recommendation would to set exact heights on the other elements, a min-height on the result, and not set the height of the container so that it all scales properly.